# Rails: Cannot display Stripe::InvalidRequestError to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I am using stripe as payment gateway (Embedded form).It works fine.

However, I can not display card errors on my website.
Errors displayed in Action controller's error page!

[image]

My controller

```
def process
 begin

 customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => totalprice, #Amount should be in cents
    :description => orderid,
    :currency    => 'aud'
  )


  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error]= e.message <-------------not working?!
  redirect_to root_url
  end

  showconfirmation
end
```

I want to display stripe error as flash message in my website. How to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are rescuing from `Stripe::CardError`, but originally you got an `Stripe::InvalidRequestError`. So, that's why your code is not being able to rescue from the error.

Invalid request errors arise when your request has invalid parameters. See [Stripe API Error reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#errors).

You have to make sure you are sending correct parameters. Or, you can rescue from `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` based on your need:

```
begin
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => totalprice, #Amount should be in cents
      :description => orderid,
      :currency    => 'aud'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError, Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
  flash[:error]= e.message
  redirect_to root_url
end
```